# Basic getAuthToken() questions

Tags: android, accountmanager

I have a couple of questions regarding the `getAuthToken()` method of the `AccountManager` class.

1. What values can "authTokenType" take? So far I have only seen it take the value "ah".
2. The `getAuthToken(Account,String,boolean,AccountManagerCallback, Handler)` has been deprecated in favor of it's overloaded counterpart which also takes a `Bundle` as a parameter. What function does it serve? *I read the docs but couldn't wrap my head around it*.

Answer (score 1):

As what in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler)) says,

> The auth token type, an authenticator-dependent string token, must not be null

This value should be the same as what you entered on your authenticator metadata file (res/xml/authenticator.xml) under `android:accountType` attribute